# Doxygen issue: chapter are all 0

Tags: c++, pdf, documentation, latex, doxygen

I have some doxygen groups defined in a fake .h file

```
@defgroup MainGroup
@brief ...

@defgroup SubGroup1
@brief ...
@ingroup MainGroup

@defgroup SubGroup1
@brief ...
@ingroup MainGroup
```

now the problem is that when generating the latex pdf, all chapters are starting with 0:

```
MainGroup
0.1
SubGroup1
0.2
SubGroup2
0.3
```

and all the pdf is a huge chapter 0.

To fix this I always need to tweak the refman.tex files by hand by inserting \chapter instead of \section, any way to have doxygen generate a proper index?

Comment: Normally it depends on a document class. Chapter is for book, try report class instead.

Comment: @Archie What is report class? Can you explain this a bit more please?

Comment: Put is as an answer for better formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `\documentclass{report}` (unlike `{book}`) if you have just `\section`s in your document (and no `\chapter`s). Now in doxygen configuration you can specify a custom header [LATEX_HEADER](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_latex_header) where you can put your `\documentclass{report}` and some styling if you wish.